# How to get time difference in hours between two dates (Django)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I am trying to subtract two dates stored in a database to get difference in hours.
However these values are in query sets, so I am unable to subtract them.

For example:

```
date1 = table.objects.values_list('field1').filter(id=1))
date2 = table.objects.values_list('field1').filter(id=2))
timediff = date1-date2
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply get the value from queryset in this way:

```
date1 = table.objects.values_list('field1', flat=True).filter(id=1))[0]
date2 = table.objects.values_list('field1', flat=True).filter(id=2))[0]
timediff = date2 - date1
```

Please note also that the timediff is `date2 - date1` and not viceversa.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'
its showing above error

Comment: yes its solved now . but it showing differance as:1:05:26.965589.
what is last "965589." value?

Comment: It's the time format, check documentation. Anyway, you can format the date as you prefer

Answer (score 0):

To get time difference, use `strptime` method from datetime.

```
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
timedelta = datetime.strptime(table.objects.values_list('field1', flat=True).filter(id=1))[0], FMT) - datetime.strptime(table.objects.values_list('field1', flat=True).filter(id=2))[0], FMT)
```

it will return a `timedelta`